# Cakephp plugin installation error

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Thanks in advance,
       AM new to cake PHP friends.first I tried to install cake PHP plugin through composer but it shows installation error plugin name was gourmet/dashboard (screenshot 1)..then I  cloned through GitHub and  pasted it in  an plugins folder and edited bootstrap file with ths Plugin::load('Gourmet/Dashboard', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true]);
and tried to load Dashboard index it shows error like Error: Gourmet/Dashboard.DashboardController could not be found.(screenshot 2)

my problems are
1.cant able to load this plugin through composer
2.when i install some plugins its goes to vendor folder why it doesn't goes to plugin folder

if i cloned Routes are working fine then y it can able to find controller

Please guys help me out on this am struggling with ths for the past two days

[screenshot1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2eWw.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgJ6V.png)

Comment: It all comes down to what version of CakePHP you are running. Since you mentioned you are new to CakePHP, I can be safe to assume you are running the stable 3.1 version. The plugin you are using is requiring 3.0 `"cakephp/cakephp": "3.0.*-dev"`.

Comment: I understand the reasoning to have the requirement there, but I think that should not be. I faced this issue developing some plugins, and the only time I add a requirement is for another library, not CakePHP.

Comment: You can do a couple of things: Request the plugin developer to remove the requirement if it the plugin will work with CakePHP 3.1.x. Another option is to create a GitHUB account, clone this plugin and update the composer.json file to remove the CakePHP requirement. And then use the your own version of this plugin.

Comment: yes Andre am using 3.1 version. now i tried with version 3.0 its working fine now thank u so much for ur help ..